# Rails auto saving(auto posting) post with 30 seconds interval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, redirect

Tried to search through in stackoverflow but doesnt find any solution to my problem.
So here it goes.I am a beginner to RoR and ajax

I wanted my Forum posts to auto submit in an interval of 30 seconds when the user is actually typing the post. Well apparently this can be achieved using ajax. The main intention of inventing this is to let other users able to read the incomplete post even while the author is typing it. So i figured out that I can do this,

IF the user is typing, I will submit the post every 30 seconds.
IF the user is done typing and submitted the post, well, he will be redirected to the topic with his post shown.

There is a problem here as we can see, auto submitting at here leads to duplicated post.
So I came up with an idea to redirect the user to a edit page, at the first time when the ajax is run.The problem is that the redirect does not work.After the first ajax submits, the page is not redirected, while the log shows that edit.html.erb is rendered.What is the problem here? Or maybe I can have a better solution to my approach?

Codes for the redirect_to part

```
def create
@topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
@post = @topic.posts.build(params[:post])
@post.forum = @topic.forum
@post.user = current_user

if @post.save
  if request.xhr?
    flash[:notice] = "Post was saved"
    redirect_to edit_post_path(@post)
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Post was successfully created."
    redirect_to topic_path(@post.topic)
  end
else
  render :action => 'new'
end
end
```

Codes for the auto saving

```
$(function() {
if ($("#new_post").length > 0) {
    setTimeout(autoSavePost, 30000); 
   }    
});

function autoSavePost() {
    for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances){
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
}
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "../posts",
data: $("#new_post").serialize(),
dataType: "script",
success: function(data) {
console.log(data);
}
});
setTimeout(autoSavePost, 30000);
}
```

Codes in application_controller.rb

```
def redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {})
if request.xhr?
   render(:edit) {|page| page.redirect_to(options)}
else
   super(options, response_status)
end
end
```

Any help is appreciated. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

To make thing simpler, i suggest using local storage or cookie to keep the auto save content. This will eliminate the effort to handle unfinished editing content, and lower the server burden.

Comment: i know that it will be a burden to the server. But I am not trying to do an auto save for that purpose..I want the unfinished editing content to be available to other user as well..e.g When I am half way typing my post, other users can already view the content